# CSS3 not work shake animation effect

Tags: html, css

I have This CSS3 animate code for shake effect in `DIV` action: (i copy this code from [HERE](https://daneden.github.io/animate.css/))

CSS CODE:

```
.shake {
    -webkit-animation-name: shake ;
    animation-name: shake;
}
@-webkit-keyframes shake {
    0%, 100% {
        -webkit-transform: translate3d(0, 0, 0);
        transform: translate3d(0, 0, 0)
    }
    10%,
    30%,
    50%,
    70%,
    90% {
        -webkit-transform: translate3d(-10px, 0, 0);
        transform: translate3d(-10px, 0, 0)
    }
    20%,
    40%,
    60%,
    80% {
        -webkit-transform: translate3d(10px, 0, 0);
        transform: translate3d(10px, 0, 0)
    }
}
@keyframes shake {
    0%, 100% {
        -webkit-transform: translate3d(0, 0, 0);
        transform: translate3d(0, 0, 0)
    }
    10%,
    30%,
    50%,
    70%,
    90% {
        -webkit-transform: translate3d(-10px, 0, 0);
        transform: translate3d(-10px, 0, 0)
    }
    20%,
    40%,
    60%,
    80% {
        -webkit-transform: translate3d(10px, 0, 0);
        transform: translate3d(10px, 0, 0)
    }
}
```

Now, in action when i see div shake action not work!?

for see css effect, How do can i fix this ?

[DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/pjra0sqk/)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The `animated` class is missing. Take a look [here](https://github.com/daneden/animate.css) to find more information on how **Animate.css** works. You actually do not need to copy the code. You can include the library into the header of your document.

```css
@-webkit-keyframes shake {
  0%, 100% {
    -webkit-transform: translate3d(0, 0, 0);
    transform: translate3d(0, 0, 0)
  }
  10%,
  30%,
  50%,
  70%,
  90% {
    -webkit-transform: translate3d(-10px, 0, 0);
    transform: translate3d(-10px, 0, 0)
  }
  20%,
  40%,
  60%,
  80% {
    -webkit-transform: translate3d(10px, 0, 0);
    transform: translate3d(10px, 0, 0)
  }
}
@keyframes shake {
  0%, 100% {
    -webkit-transform: translate3d(0, 0, 0);
    transform: translate3d(0, 0, 0)
  }
  10%,
  30%,
  50%,
  70%,
  90% {
    -webkit-transform: translate3d(-10px, 0, 0);
    transform: translate3d(-10px, 0, 0)
  }
  20%,
  40%,
  60%,
  80% {
    -webkit-transform: translate3d(10px, 0, 0);
    transform: translate3d(10px, 0, 0)
  }
}

/* add this class */
.animated {
  -webkit-animation-duration:1s;
  animation-duration: 1s;
  -webkit-animation-fill-mode: both;
  animation-fill-mode: both;
}
.shake {
  -webkit-animation-name: shake;
  animation-name: shake
}
```

```html
<div class="animated shake">Shake this text</div>
```

Comment: Who is on a down vote spree? Did that on my last answer as well, though correct.

Comment: Don't know, but i consider the OP's question related to **animate.css**, this is why i have added the extra `.animated` class. Sure it can be done without it, but in respect to the author of **animate.css** i thought it would be a good idea.

Comment: All answers here are downvoted don't know why and all are correct

Comment: @ketan don't know why? was not me.

Answer (score 0):

Working, your missing the animation-duration: 4s;

```
  @-webkit-keyframes shake {
    0%, 100% {
        -webkit-transform: translate3d(0, 0, 0);
        transform: translate3d(0, 0, 0)
    }
    10%,
    30%,
    50%,
    70%,
    90% {
        -webkit-transform: translate3d(-10px, 0, 0);
        transform: translate3d(-10px, 0, 0)
    }
    20%,
    40%,
    60%,
    80% {
        -webkit-transform: translate3d(10px, 0, 0);
        transform: translate3d(10px, 0, 0)
    }
}
@keyframes shake {
    0%, 100% {
        -webkit-transform: translate3d(0, 0, 0);
        transform: translate3d(0, 0, 0)
    }
    10%,
    30%,
    50%,
    70%,
    90% {
        -webkit-transform: translate3d(-10px, 0, 0);
        transform: translate3d(-10px, 0, 0)
    }
    20%,
    40%,
    60%,
    80% {
        -webkit-transform: translate3d(10px, 0, 0);
        transform: translate3d(10px, 0, 0)
    }
}
.shake {
    -webkit-animation-name: shake;
    animation-name: shake;
    animation-duration: 4s;
}
```

Fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/pjra0sqk/2/

Answer (score 0):

It is becuase you didn't give `animation-duration: 1s;`

Just give it solved your issue.

```
.shake {
    -webkit-animation-name: shake;
    animation-name: shake;
    animation-duration: 1s;
    -webkit-animation-duration:1s;
}
```

Check your updated [Fiddle.](http://jsfiddle.net/pjra0sqk/4/)